# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
 CompanyDAO companyDAO = new CompanyDAO();
 List companyList = companyDAO.getAllCompanyList();
```

MycompanyList contains a data of like this :

```
 [[1, Agastha Medical Center], [2, Agastha Asthma]]
```

Now i want to iterate the values and i want to pass a value of 1 to query but when i am placing this inside of a for loop i am getting

```
for(int k=0;k<=companyList.size();k++){

List companyId =companyList.get(k);  //  [1, Agastha Medical Center]  for k=0;

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List
```

I need to read value of 1 alone inside of for loop how can i do this ?

Comment: dont use generic `List`, use typed `List<Company>`

Answer (score 2):

As your companyList is of raw type, you have to cast the object obtained from it explicitly

```
List companyId = (List) companyList.get(k);
```

But it would be better to provide your API with types so that casting is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

you have to type cast the list

```
for(int k=0;k<=companyList.size();k++){

List companyId =(List)companyList.get(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Don't use raw types use generics. example : `Arraylist<String>`
> 2. List companyId =companyList.get(k) is your error.  companyList.get(k) returns an object. you have to typecast it to
>      appropriate type explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the Type of list you want to get from CompanyDAO

Ex. `ArrayList<Company>`, `List<Company>`